# Fortify Issue on Android: Dynamic Code Evaluation: Unsafe Deserialization

Tags: java, android, deserialization, fortify

I run fortify scan on an Android Project (Java), and got some issues.
The report did not suggest how to fix it.

It marked the launcher class which have manifest-declared receivers as "Dynamic Code Evaluation: Unsafe Deserialization". But I did not deserialize any object.

```
    <activity
        android:name=".LaunchScreen"
        android:screenOrientation="portrait">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
```

I searched from Google, most of them are Java object deserialization, and none of them are related to Android.

---

Result from scanning:

**Dynamic Code Evaluation: Unsafe Deserialization**

**Abstract** Deserializing user-controlled object streams at runtime can allow attackers to execute arbitrary code on the server, abuse application logic or lead to denial of service.

**Explanation** Java serialization turns object graphs into byte streams containing the objects themselves and the necessary metadata to reconstruct them from the byte stream. Developers can create custom code to aid in the process of deserializing Java objects, where they may even replace the deserialized objects with different objects, or proxies. The customized deserialization process takes place during objects reconstruction before the objects are returned to the application and cast into expected types. By the time developers try to enforce an expected type, code may have already been executed. Custom deserialization routines are defined in the serializable classes which need to be present in the runtime classpath and cannot be injected by the attacker so the exploitability of these attacks depends on the classes available in the application environment. Unfortunately, common third party classes or even JDK classes can be abused to exhaust JVM resources, deploy malicious files, or run arbitrary code. Certain protocols use Java serialization behind the scenes in the transport layer. RMI and JMX are examples of these protocols.

**Recommendation** If possible, do not deserialize untrusted data without validating the contents of the object stream. In order to validate classes being deserialized, the look-ahead deserialization pattern should be used. The object stream will first contain the class description metadata and then the serialized bytes of their member fields. The Java serialization process allows developers to read the class description and decide whether to proceed with the deserialization of the object or abort it. In order to do so, it is necessary to subclass java.io.ObjectInputStream and provide a custom implementation of the resolveClass(ObjectStreamClass desc) method where class validation and verification should Sep 29, 2016, 5:09 PM Copyright 2015 Hewlett Packard Enterprise Development LP 13 take place. There are existing implementations of the look-ahead pattern that can be easily used, such as the Apache Commons IO (org.apache.commons.io.serialization.ValidatingObjectInputStream). Always use a strict whitelist approach to only deserialize expected types. A blacklist approach is not recommended since attackers can use many available gadgets to bypass the blacklist. Also, keep in mind that although some classes to achieve code execution are publicly known, there may be others that are unknown or undisclosed, so a whitelist approach will always be preferred. Any class allowed in the whitelist should be audited to make sure it is safe to deserialize. To avoid denial of service attacks, it is recommended that you override the resolveObject(Object obj) method in order to count how many objects are being deserialized and abort the deserialization when a threshold is surpassed. When deserialization takes place in library, or framework (e.g. when using JMX, RMI, JMS, HTTP Invokers) the above recommendation is not useful since it is beyond the developer's control. In those cases, you may want to make sure that these protocols meet the following requirements: - Not exposed publicly. - Use authentication. - Use integrity checks. - Use encryption. In addition, HPE Security Fortify Runtime provides security controls to be enforced every time the application performs a deserialization from an ObjectInputStream, protecting both application code but also library and framework code from this type of attack.

Comment: You should look on Android-specific vulnerability scanners, then.

Comment: How did you solve this issue ? Could you please share your experience ?